# Stack pkgdb in Docker

Tags: docker, haskell, haskell-stack

I have a Dockerfile which installs Stack with a global project configuration and also runs `stack install` for a bunch of stuff, so in the Docker image, we have `stack` plus some packages in the package databases.

So when I'm at a bash prompt of a running container of the image, I see

```
$ stack --version
Version 2.5.1, Git revision d6ab861544918185236cf826cb2028abb266d6d5 x86_64 hpack-0.33.0
```

```
$ stack exec ghc-pkg list
/opt/stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.8.4/lib/ghc-8.8.4/package.conf.d
    Cabal-3.0.1.0
    array-0.5.4.0
    base-4.13.0.0
...
/opt/stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/fffebb3fddcd52e7f38de3e253571498d665f4223658a7bafc9d5035b02e4ef3/8.8.4/pkgdb
    Boolean-0.2.4
...
/opt/stack/global-project/.stack-work/install/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/fffebb3fddcd52e7f38de3e253571498d665f4223658a7bafc9d5035b02e4ef3/8.8.4/pkgdb
    ghc-parser-0.2.2.0
    hvega-0.11.0.0
...
```

Then I install a new package `vinyl`.

```
$ stack install vinyl
vinyl> configure
vinyl> Configuring vinyl-0.13.0...
vinyl> build
...
vinyl> copy/register
vinyl> Installing library in /opt/stack/snapshots/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/1d59f4b6093ea66bb0acc2d4f8757c137c4f3937b8a5131f44a85db5db236e4e/8.8.4/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-8.8.4/vinyl-0.13.0-22RZxwfYh3i37XmCDd1atp
```

But `vinyl` has been installed in a snapshot database with a different hash, and when I try to use it, it's not there.

```
$ stack repl

Note: No local targets specified, so a plain ghci will be started with no package hiding or package options.
      
      You are using snapshot: lts-16.23
      
      If you want to use package hiding and options, then you can try one of the following:
      
      * If you want to start a different project configuration than /opt/stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can use
        stack init to create a new stack.yaml for the packages in the current directory. 
        
      * If you want to use the project configuration
        at /opt/stack/global-project/stack.yaml, then you can add to its 'packages' field.
      
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.8.4: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /tmp/haskell-stack-ghci/2a3bbd58/ghci-script

Prelude> import Data.Vinyl

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Vinyl’
    Perhaps you meant Data.Kind (from base-4.13.0.0)
```

This is the workflow I want. How do I get it? Why does Stack install into a different snapshot database in this situation?

Comment: I rebuilt the Docker image and now when I `stack install vinyl`, the package gets installed in the one snapshot database and I can `stack repl` and `import Data.Vinyl` as epxected. So my problem is solved. But I still don't know why.

Comment: I encountered this problem again and I'm still trying to find the answer.

Comment: Here's the only discussion I can find about this in the user manual https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#different-databases

Comment: Okay in this case the package that I'm building `stack build palette` is not in the Stackage resolver, so maybe that's why it's going into a different snapshot database...

Comment: I think that hash in the snapshot path is the derived resolver of the stack.yaml resolver + the extra-deps. When I stack build a package that's not in the derived resolver, then a new derived resolver is calculated based on the old derived resolver + the new package as a new extra-deps.

Comment: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/build_command/#target-syntax

“... and package index (e.g. Hackage). If it's found in the package index, then the latest version of that package from the index is implicitly added to your extra dependencies.”